# Problem with inheritance child classes in python Pygame

Tags: python

In my boid simulation, I have a `Vehicle` class with an attribute that looks like this:

```
class Vehicle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       image = pygame.Surface((10,10), pygame.SRCALPHA) 
       #pygame.SRCALPHA does not seem to make a difference wether I have it or not
```

Then, I have two subclasses of this Vehicle class, like this, each basically looking like this:

```
class Predator(Vehicle):
   pygame.draw.polygon(Vehicle.image, pygame.Color('grey'), [(15,5), (0,2), (0,8)])
```

```
class Boid(Vehicle):
   pygame.draw.polygon(Vehicle.image, pygame.Color('pink'), [(15,5), (0,2), (0,8)])
```

I created a predator object and a boid object, but all the objects are grey and not 1 grey and 5 pinks. Any help?
If you need any extra code please comment.

Comment: run code in `__init__`

Comment: Okay, I will try

Comment: and use `self.` - `self.image = pygame.Surface(...)` and `polygon(self.image, ...)`